Google Sheets Comma Delimited Lookup
Long-time lurker, first-time poster.
I have a list of device nicknames (i.e. "Laptop #1") and their associated device names (i.e. "B1-101").
What I would like is to be able to pull device names from a comma-delimited list of device nicknames sourced in a single cell (i.e. "Laptop #1, Laptop #2") resulting in their associated device names in a comma-delimited list in the formula's cell (i.e. "B1-101, B1-102").
I can easily grab the device name based on its nickname via multiple methods (i.e. vlookup, index/match, filter/regexmatch, query, etc.), but once the cell contains a string beyond the simple single-cell device nickname (i.e. "Laptop #1, Laptop #2), all the methods I've used break since the comma-delimited list in the single cell is treated, understandably, as a single string.
My goal is to have the single-cell list of device nicknames to be used to "lookup" the unsorted search range and result in a single-cell showing the correct comma-delimited list of associated device names (i.e. "Laptop #1, Laptop #2" should result in "B1-101, B1-102").
Below are the example nicknames and device names:



Nicknames
Device Names




Laptop #1
B1-101


Laptop #2
B1-102



Here's the search source (Nickname List) and the intended search results (Device Lookup):



Nickname List
Device Lookup




Laptop #1
B1-101


Laptop #1, Laptop #2
B1-101, B1-102



In the above Nickname List/Device Lookup table shown, my attempts using vlookup, query, and index/match will work for the A2 search ("Laptop #1" resulting in B2 showing "B1-101"), but not for the A3 search ("Laptop #1, Laptop #2" intended to result in B3 showing "B1-101, B1-102").
I've seen some more complicated formulae that utilize LAMBDA to store values. I'm assuming this is the route I'll have to take, splitting the source list by ", " and storing each resulting nickname value to be searched, storing the resulting device name lookup matches, and concatenating the results.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.


You may try:
=map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,textjoin(", ",1,index(xlookup(split(Σ,", ",),A:A,B:B,))))))



Adjust the formula ranges as needed


That's phenomenal! Very much appreciated. Could you explain what's going on here, especially as it relates to your use of map, lambda, and sigma?
